# Reverting changes made to external in Subversion

Tags: svn, revert

My Subversion repository has several externals, one of which I was working with.  I accidentally removed several files that I needed, so I went to revert them:

```
$ svn revert -R ~/Code/project/external1
Skipped '~/Code/project/external1'
```

I thought this was odd, so I tried removing the entire directory:

```
$ rm ~/Code/project/external1 -r
$ svn revert -R ~/Code/project/external1
Skipped '~/Code/project/external1'
```

It seems Subversion doesn't want to descend into the external.  How do I cause Subversion to revert the directory, in both the ideal first case *and* in my rashly-considered second case?

Comment: See https://forgetfulprogrammer.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/subversion-revert-with-externals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each external directory is basically its own self-contained working copy. It looks like SVN doesn't like doing operations from your real working copy on the external working copy. So just take advantage of the underlying mechanism and use the external's working copy:

```
cd ~/Code/project/external1
svn revert -R .
```

Or directly from the current folder (great for scripts)

```
svn revert -R .
svn revert -R ./External_a
svn revert -R ./External_b
svn revert -R ./External_c/sub_external_i
svn revert -R ./External_c/sub_external_j
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update the base directory where the external property is declared:

```
svn update ~/Code/project
```

Subversion will notice that the external is out of date/missing and re-instantiate everything.

Comment: To clarify, that's after the external folder has been deleted as in your second case.